# How to add a runtime library on Gradle in the build command

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle file that I want to use to build a Spring Boot microservice for multiple projects. I have created a custom library with some classes that should not be in all of the projects but I don't want to have to edit the build.gradle file when I build the microservice depending on which project I will use it in.
How can I add a command/parameter to gradle build that can add runtime libraries to the Spring Boot app?

Something like (just an exaple):

```
gradle buildDocker -PaddRuntime=com.skios.lib:lib-common:0.2.35
```

Thanks for any directions

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your issue fully and thus not convinced this is the best solution.

But since a Gradle build script accepts code, you can have conditionals in a dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    if (project.hasProperty('addRuntime')) {
        runtimeOnly('com.skios.lib:lib-common:0.2.35')
    }
}
```

and then on the command line: `./gradlew buildDocker -PaddRuntime`

Comment: After you wrote it, it looks obvious but I had no idea you can include a runtimeOnly inside an "if" clause. I will test on the fly and confirm. Thanks!

Comment: BTW... is there a way to add the value or addRuntime property as the parameter to runtimeOnly()? Somethin like runtimeOnly(${addRuntime}) ?

Comment: Sure and if that notation does not work, `project.getProperty('addRuntime')` will.